# UI input with reactive-banana-wx

Tags: haskell, reactive-programming, reactive-banana

How do you get the content of ui elements when using reactive-banana? The event0 returns an event of type `Event ()`, which has unit type instead of the type of the control. event1 takes an event of type `Event w (a -> IO ())`, but command is of type `Event w (IO ())`. mapAccumE and mapAccumB takes pure functions as parameters, so `get text foo` can't be used with them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, you want to work with functions instead of data.  If you're thinking "How do I create a behavior which has the current text in a box", you don't.  Instead you write functions that take the current text as a parameter, and pass it in when necessary.  Suppose you want to print the contents of a textbox when a button is pressed.  Then you would do something like this:

```
eButton :: NetworkDescription (Event ())
eButton = event0 button command

network = do
  pressButton <- eButton
  reactimate $ (\() -> get text foo >>= print) <$> pressButton
```

If you need to get input into a Behavior, you can similarly use a function with type `Behavior (String -> a)` (or whatever type you need), and then just pass the string in at the point of the `reactimate` call.

Answer (score 4):

(Author of [reactive-banana](http://haskell.org/haskellwiki/Reactive-banana) speaking. Sorry for the late reply, the possibility of questions being asked here didn't even cross my mind. :-) )

I discovered today that I omitted a very crucial feature from the library: getting the content of a UI element as a `Behavior`. Embarassing! :-D

[John](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6544599/ui-input-with-reactive-banana-wx/6551380#6551380) describes the current workaround, but the next version of reactive-banana will include the missing feature.

EDIT: I have released reactive-banana [version 0.4](http://apfelmus.nfshost.com/blog/2011/07/07-frp-banana-0-4.html) which now includes the functionality in form of a function

```
fromPoll :: IO a -> NetworkDescription (Behavior a)
```